# Semantics of a string literal as a datatype

Tags: typescript, types

This excerpt is from `lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts`

```
interface Promise<T> {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Promise";
}
```

The meaning of readonly is self-evident, and `[Symbol.toStringTag]` presumably means "the function property named `toString`".

What puzzles me is the use of a string literal as a *type*. I don't imagine this has the same meaning as

```
readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string = "Promise";
```

or they would have written it that way. So what is the meaning of a string literal as a type, and what are the run-time implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a minor correction: the `[`[`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag)`]` is not a function, but a  [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)-named property checked by the default `toString()` function.  The idea is that something meeting the `Promise` interface will generally include the string `"Promise"` in its string description.

---

Probably the best answer to this question is in the TypeScript Handbook under [Advanced Types: String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).

If the type of a variable is a string, number, or boolean literal, it means the variable can take *only* that value:

```
const yes: 'foo' = 'foo'; // okay
const no: 'foo' = 'bar'; // error, 'bar' is not assignable to 'foo'
```

This has several uses:

- unions of literals can represent an enumeration of allowable values.  (e.g., `type ShirtSize = 'S'|'M'|'L'|'XL'` or `type starRating = 1|2|3|4|5`)
- string literals can be used to represent property keys. (e.g., `Record<'foo'|'bar',number>` is essentially equivalent to `{foo: number; bar: number}`)
- string literals can be used as tags to discriminate types: (e.g., `type Dog = {type: 'dog', bark():void}; type Cat = {type: 'cat', meow():void}; declare let animal: Dog | Cat; if (animal.type === 'dog') animal.bark(); else animal.meow();`)
- and more.. look at the doc listed above for more info

---

Note well: TypeScript's type system is not emitted into the JavaScript.  That means you will tend to find yourself repeating the literal: once as a type, and once as a value:

```
const foo: 'foo' = 'foo';
```

The first `'foo'` is the type, and the second is the value.  If you leave off the value,

```
const foo: 'foo';
```

then you have an undefined value at runtime, which is bad.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

> What puzzles me is the use of a string literal as a type.

The string literal type constrains all `Promise<T>` implementations to set the value of `[Symbol.toStringTag]` to the string "Promise".

### Long Example

```
class MyPromise1<T> implements Promise<T> {
    public readonly [Symbol.toStringTag] = "Promise"; // Allowed
    public then = () => null; 
    public catch = () => null;
}

class MyPromise2<T> implements Promise<T> {
    public readonly [Symbol.toStringTag] = "Foobar"; // Error!
    public then = () => null; 
    public catch = () => null;
}

interface SomeThing<T> {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Promise" | "Foobar";
}

class MySomeThing1<T> implements SomeThing<T> {
    public readonly [Symbol.toStringTag] = "Promise"; // Allowed
}

class MySomeThing2<T> implements SomeThing<T> {
    public readonly [Symbol.toStringTag] = "Foobar"; // Allowed
}

class MySomeThing3<T> implements SomeThing<T> {
    public readonly [Symbol.toStringTag] = "Foobaz"; // Error!
}

interface OtherThing<T> {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string; 
}

class MyOtherThing<T> implements OtherThing<T> {
    public readonly [Symbol.toStringTag] = "Any string is..."; // Allowed
}
```

Comment: Hi, Shaun. I accepted the other answer because it's more comprehensive. Stack Overflow used to have a chat facility, do you happen to know how to use it? I'd like to talk with you for a minute about the content of an exchange between me and Rick S regarding .net core yesterday.